# my Mac is restating over and over

Tags: mac, macos

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, late 2011) When I upgraded to Yosemite, it was fine until a month ago, then there is no day that my computer does not restart/freeze randomly. I am really tired of it, so any help is really appreciated. What I have done? Basically everything:

Start up in safe mode
Reset parameter random-access memory (PRAM)
Repair the startup disk/ disk permissions,
I tried to use Apple Hardware Test, but I get error 2002D error
After all that I did, I even clean installed Yosemite (I mean, I formatted my disk and then installed again) it was okay for a week but then started again.

Here is the problem what i normally received 
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553

Can you please share your knowledge with me?

Please find below the console message

```
01/03/15 17:55:37,816 tccd[700]: Failed to create /var/empty/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC (13)
01/03/15 17:55:38,019 sandboxd[354]: ([699]) AssetCacheLocato(699) deny ipc-posix-shm-read-data /tmp/com.apple.csseed.77
01/03/15 17:55:52,588 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[702]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
01/03/15 17:55:52,836 com.apple.SecurityServer[52]: Session 100022 created
01/03/15 17:55:53,068 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 17:55:53,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(704) deny mach-lookup com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache
01/03/15 17:55:53,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(704) deny file-issue-extension /Users/mohammadgoodarzi/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite
01/03/15 17:55:53,087 QuickLookSatellite[704]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/mohammadgoodarzi/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite. Errno:1
01/03/15 17:55:53,088 QuickLookSatellite[704]: Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/Users/mohammadgoodarzi/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite. Errno:1
01/03/15 17:55:53,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: QuickLookSatelli(704) deny mach-lookup com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache
01/03/15 17:55:53,188 QuickLookSatellite[704]: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
01/03/15 17:55:53,188 QuickLookSatellite[704]: Invalid Connection ID 0
01/03/15 17:55:53,236 sandboxd[354]: ([704]) QuickLookSatelli(704) deny file-issue-extension /Users/mohammadgoodarzi/Library/Caches/com.apple.quicklook.satellite
01/03/15 17:55:56,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on 87E7641F-329A-4C5E-8C5C-ACCFD0AFED95 on device disk2s2
01/03/15 17:56:01,772 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 17:56:24,622 login[708]: USER_PROCESS: 708 ttys000
01/03/15 17:56:26,959 login[708]: DEAD_PROCESS: 708 ttys000
01/03/15 17:56:33,780 WindowServer[196]: WSGetSurfaceInWindow : Invalid surface 1071326293 for window 146
01/03/15 17:56:59,523 Disk Utility[713]: Failed to connect (cancelRecreate) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 17:56:59,523 Disk Utility[713]: Failed to connect (repairSheetInfo) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 17:56:59,705 Disk Utility[713]: 10.4-style NSNumberFormatter method called on a 10.0-style formatter, which doesn't work. Break on _NSNumberFormatter_Log_New_Methods_On_Old_Formatters to debug. This message will only be logged once.
01/03/15 17:58:27,000 kernel[0]: considerRebuildOfPrelinkedKernel prebuild rebuild has expired
01/03/15 17:58:27,000 kernel[0]: USBF:    1532.371    IOUSBCompositeDriver(v210w)::GetConfigDescriptor - GetFullConfigDescriptor(0) #2 returned NULL, trying ResetDevice and then trying again
01/03/15 17:58:27,889 UserEventAgent[17]: assertion failed: 14C109: com.apple.telemetry + 23794 [B033615E-AC6E-3C72-A493-A728F602B10C]: 0xffffffffe00002be
01/03/15 17:58:38,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on DiskMaker X on device disk3s2
01/03/15 17:58:45,054 Disk Utility[720]: Failed to connect (cancelRecreate) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 17:58:45,055 Disk Utility[720]: Failed to connect (repairSheetInfo) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 17:58:45,234 Disk Utility[720]: 10.4-style NSNumberFormatter method called on a 10.0-style formatter, which doesn't work. Break on _NSNumberFormatter_Log_New_Methods_On_Old_Formatters to debug. This message will only be logged once.
01/03/15 17:58:55,000 kernel[0]: SerialATAPI device reconfiguration did not complete successfully.  (failedCommandInfo = 0x1)
01/03/15 17:59:29,990 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 17:59:39,679 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:40,080 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:40,111 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:47,809 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:47,809 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:47,810 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:48,057 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 17:59:48,123 networkd[216]: -[NETClientConnection scrubParametersForEntitlements:] client com.apple.WebKi.724 setting source application without entitlement
01/03/15 18:03:49,270 apsd[49]: Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.aps-connection-initiate' for ManagedClientAgent[729]
01/03/15 18:03:49,271 apsd[49]: Peer connection [pid=729] lacks APSConnectionInitiateEntitlement
01/03/15 18:03:49,305 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.PubSub.Agent[730]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.pubsub.ipc
01/03/15 18:03:49,305 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.PubSub.Agent[730]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.pubsub.notification
01/03/15 18:03:50,410 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:03:52,131 ManagedClientAgent[729]: No Device Enrollment record info was found
01/03/15 18:04:12,140 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:04:12,208 com.apple.iCloudHelper[735]: objc[735]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
01/03/15 18:04:12,218 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:04:42,040 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:05:37,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a  MAC AUTH succeeded
01/03/15 18:05:37,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
01/03/15 18:05:37,000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:05:37,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:05:37,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 6
01/03/15 18:05:37,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
01/03/15 18:05:38,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
01/03/15 18:06:34,434 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:06:39,236 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:07:15,150 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:10:12,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a  MAC AUTH succeeded
01/03/15 18:10:12,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
01/03/15 18:10:12,000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:10:12,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:10:12,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 6
01/03/15 18:10:12,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
01/03/15 18:10:13,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
01/03/15 18:10:15,000 kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): AA00000000001155 0x3f0 0x5607 0x1100, 2
01/03/15 18:10:17,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted 87E7641F-329A-4C5E-8C5C-ACCFD0AFED95 on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:10:33,572 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:12:12,119 com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[763]: Failed to connect (colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:12:12,119 com.apple.WebKit.Plugin.64[763]: Failed to connect (view) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:12:57,773 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
01/03/15 18:12:59,247 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[764]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
01/03/15 18:13:00,866 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
01/03/15 18:13:00,997 Disk Utility[766]: Failed to connect (cancelRecreate) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:13:00,997 Disk Utility[766]: Failed to connect (repairSheetInfo) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:13:01,164 Disk Utility[766]: 10.4-style NSNumberFormatter method called on a 10.0-style formatter, which doesn't work. Break on _NSNumberFormatter_Log_New_Methods_On_Old_Formatters to debug. This message will only be logged once.
01/03/15 18:13:11,000 kernel[0]: SerialATAPI device reconfiguration did not complete successfully.  (failedCommandInfo = 0x1)
01/03/15 18:13:36,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a  MAC AUTH succeeded
01/03/15 18:13:36,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
01/03/15 18:13:36,000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:13:36,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:13:36,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 6
01/03/15 18:13:36,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
01/03/15 18:13:37,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
01/03/15 18:14:43,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on 87E7641F-329A-4C5E-8C5C-ACCFD0AFED95 on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:14:57,000 kernel[0]: hfs: Initializing the journal (joffset 0x3c000 sz 0x800000)...
01/03/15 18:14:57,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Install Mavericks on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:14:57,987 mds[32]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7ff661848000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:3 SpotLoc:/Volumes/Install Mavericks/.Spotlight-V100 SpotVerLoc:/Volumes/Install Mavericks/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1 occlude:0 /Volumes/Install Mavericks
01/03/15 18:14:58,031 fseventsd[20]: could not open <</Volumes/Install Mavericks/.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid>> (No such file or directory)
01/03/15 18:14:58,031 fseventsd[20]: Failed to load UUID.  Removing all old log files in /Volumes/Install Mavericks/.fseventsd
01/03/15 18:14:58,031 fseventsd[20]: log dir: /Volumes/Install Mavericks/.fseventsd getting new uuid: B09CBA9B-2F82-4DD8-97C5-18BE1364D2EF
01/03/15 18:15:11,198 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[785]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
01/03/15 18:15:23,730 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:15:39,809 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:15:46,472 discoveryd[48]: Basic DNSResolver  Error 9 on socket - this might be a closed socket
01/03/15 18:15:47,023 discoveryd[48]: Basic DNSResolver  Re-Binding to random udp port 62189
01/03/15 18:17:05,604 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
01/03/15 18:17:07,992 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
01/03/15 18:17:19,812 Spotlight[319]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
01/03/15 18:17:53,671 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:20:55,057 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:21:59,974 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:23:10,348 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a  MAC AUTH succeeded
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 6
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
01/03/15 18:26:13,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
01/03/15 18:26:17,026 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:28:52,652 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
01/03/15 18:28:56,516 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
01/03/15 18:28:58,479 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a  MAC AUTH succeeded
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a Unsolicited  Auth
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to 40:f2:01:83:ee:9a
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 6
01/03/15 18:29:29,000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
01/03/15 18:29:30,000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
01/03/15 18:30:29,939 Skype[850]: Failed to get contents of directory "/Users/mohammadgoodarzi/Library/Logs/Skype". The file “Skype” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
01/03/15 18:30:31,367 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:33:04,371 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: assertion failed: 14C109: launchd + 160074 [A205063E-A036-3409-A251-C95F96607511]: 0xe
01/03/15 18:33:04,371 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: assertion failed: 14C109: launchd + 160074 [A205063E-A036-3409-A251-C95F96607511]: 0xe
01/03/15 18:33:52,200 apsd[49]: Failed entitlement check 'com.apple.private.aps-connection-initiate' for ManagedClientAgent[858]
01/03/15 18:33:52,200 apsd[49]: Peer connection [pid=858] lacks APSConnectionInitiateEntitlement
01/03/15 18:33:55,562 ManagedClientAgent[858]: No Device Enrollment record info was found
01/03/15 18:39:55,038 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
01/03/15 18:41:10,789 UserEventAgent[284]: com.apple.TMHelperAgent.SetupOffer enabled
01/03/15 18:41:12,539 UserEventAgent[284]: com.apple.TMHelperAgent.SetupOffer enabled
01/03/15 18:41:13,856 storedownloadd[416]: setting error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 8.)"
01/03/15 18:41:13,983 storeassetd[413]: AssetServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fced1644f50> connection from pid 416 with interface <AssetServiceInterface: 0x7fced1626a30> (PID 416)
01/03/15 18:41:14,077 storeaccountd[347]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7f93984e8f90> connection from pid 416 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7f939a148fb0> (PID 416)
01/03/15 18:41:14,310 com.apple.CommerceKit.TransactionService[886]: TransactionServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fd852605250> connection from pid 416 with interface <TransactionServiceInterface: 0x7fd852608ef0> (PID 416)
01/03/15 18:41:14,313 storeaccountd[347]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7f939a554c10> connection from pid 886 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7f939a54fd80> (PID 886)
01/03/15 18:41:14,317 storeaccountd[347]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7f939a55ced0> connection from pid 416 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7f939a55f540> (PID 416)
01/03/15 18:41:15,115 storeaccountd[347]: ADI: {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, max-age=0, private, no-transform, must-revalidate, no-store";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 258;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:41:15 GMT";
    Expires = "Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:41:15 GMT";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000";
    "apple-timing-app" = "8 ms";
    "edge-control" = "no-store";
    "x-apple-application-instance" = 102065;
    "x-apple-application-site" = ST11;
    "x-apple-asset-version" = 0;
    "x-apple-date-generated" = "Sun, 01 Mar 2015 17:41:15 GMT";
    "x-apple-jingle-correlation-key" = NL2YLGRJMOJOZWGFUQEHVQ5HZM;
    "x-apple-lokamai-no-cache" = true;
    "x-apple-request-store-front" = "143446-2,13";
    "x-webobjects-loadaverage" = 0;
}
01/03/15 18:41:15,116 storeaccountd[347]: AccountServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7f939a46edb0> connection from pid 416 with interface <AccountServiceInterface: 0x7f939a364a90> (PID 416)
01/03/15 18:41:15,241 Install OS X Mavericks[887]: Using your own bundle identifier as an NSUserDefaults suite name does not make sense and will not work. Break on _NSUserDefaults_Log_Nonsensical_Suites to find this
01/03/15 18:41:15,379 storeassetd[413]: AssetServiceDelegate: Accepting new connection <NSXPCConnection: 0x7fced162c280> connection from pid 416 with interface <AssetServiceInterface: 0x7fced1631dd0> (PID 416)
01/03/15 18:41:28,218 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
01/03/15 18:41:30,390 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[894]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
01/03/15 18:41:32,658 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
01/03/15 18:41:34,645 login[898]: USER_PROCESS: 898 ttys000
01/03/15 18:41:41,439 mdworker[902]: code validation failed in the process of getting signing information: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -67062.)"
01/03/15 18:41:42,128 login[898]: DEAD_PROCESS: 898 ttys000
01/03/15 18:43:02,418 login[907]: USER_PROCESS: 907 ttys000
01/03/15 18:43:10,535 sudo[911]: mohammadgoodarzi : TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/Users/mohammadgoodarzi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app --nointeraction
01/03/15 18:43:27,318 CoreServicesUIAgent[307]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff7523bc60> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff7523bf70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>
01/03/15 18:43:27,326 Dock[313]: LaunchPad: __53-[LPAppManager(StoreSupport) _acceptStoreConnection:]_block_invoke app store xpc message error: Connection invalid
01/03/15 18:43:27,342 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.63780108-CFC5-4AD5-A199-6238053358D1[684]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
01/03/15 18:43:57,423 sudo[914]: mohammadgoodarzi : TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/Users/mohammadgoodarzi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Install Mavericks --applicationpath /Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app --nointeraction
01/03/15 18:44:03,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Install Mavericks on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:44:04,798 WindowServer[196]: WSGetSurfaceInWindow : Invalid surface 1307626948 for window 180
01/03/15 18:44:04,798 WindowServer[196]: WSGetSurfaceInWindow : Invalid surface 1307626948 for window 180
01/03/15 18:44:07,065 coreservicesd[77]: Received request to reset fmod watch. Latest received id is 2522519252758. Latest sent id is 2522519252758
01/03/15 18:44:14,896 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
01/03/15 18:44:17,699 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
01/03/15 18:44:17,934 Disk Utility[920]: Failed to connect (cancelRecreate) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:44:17,934 Disk Utility[920]: Failed to connect (repairSheetInfo) outlet from (DUWindowController) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:44:18,140 Disk Utility[920]: 10.4-style NSNumberFormatter method called on a 10.0-style formatter, which doesn't work. Break on _NSNumberFormatter_Log_New_Methods_On_Old_Formatters to debug. This message will only be logged once.
01/03/15 18:44:28,000 kernel[0]: SerialATAPI device reconfiguration did not complete successfully.  (failedCommandInfo = 0x1)
01/03/15 18:44:30,662 WindowServer[196]: WSGetSurfaceInWindow : Invalid surface 1071573646 for window 235
01/03/15 18:44:36,000 kernel[0]: USBF:    4300.701    The IOUSBFamily is having trouble enumerating a USB device that has been plugged in.  It will keep retrying.  (Port 3 of Hub at 0xfa100000)
01/03/15 18:44:36,000 kernel[0]: USBF:    4300.701    The IOUSBFamily was not able to enumerate a device.
01/03/15 18:44:42,000 kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): AA00000000001155 0x3f0 0x5607 0x1100, 2
01/03/15 18:44:43,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Install Mavericks on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:44:56,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Install Mavericks on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:45:11,000 kernel[0]: hfs: Initializing the journal (joffset 0x3c000 sz 0x800000)...
01/03/15 18:45:11,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Untitled on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:45:11,827 mds[32]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7ff6620ba800 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:3 SpotLoc:/Volumes/Untitled/.Spotlight-V100 SpotVerLoc:/Volumes/Untitled/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1 occlude:0 /Volumes/Untitled
01/03/15 18:45:11,945 fseventsd[20]: could not open <</Volumes/Untitled/.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid>> (No such file or directory)
01/03/15 18:45:11,945 fseventsd[20]: Failed to load UUID.  Removing all old log files in /Volumes/Untitled/.fseventsd
01/03/15 18:45:11,945 fseventsd[20]: log dir: /Volumes/Untitled/.fseventsd getting new uuid: 46C40038-47EC-4C19-89AD-EF209A16DAE6
01/03/15 18:45:44,657 sudo[955]: mohammadgoodarzi : TTY=ttys000 ; PWD=/Users/mohammadgoodarzi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app --nointeraction
01/03/15 18:45:44,000 kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Untitled on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:45:47,427 coreservicesd[77]: Received request to reset fmod watch. Latest received id is 4336413543849. Latest sent id is 4336413543849
01/03/15 18:45:55,000 kernel[0]: hfs: Initializing the journal (joffset 0x3c000 sz 0x800000)...
01/03/15 18:45:55,000 kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Install OS X Mavericks on device disk2s2
01/03/15 18:45:55,667 mds[32]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7ff664092000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:3 SpotLoc:/Volumes/Install OS X Mavericks/.Spotlight-V100 SpotVerLoc:/Volumes/Install OS X Mavericks/.Spotlight-V100/Store-V1 occlude:0 /Volumes/Install OS X Mavericks
01/03/15 18:45:55,713 fseventsd[20]: could not open <</Volumes/Install OS X Mavericks/.fseventsd/fseventsd-uuid>> (No such file or directory)
01/03/15 18:45:55,713 fseventsd[20]: Failed to load UUID.  Removing all old log files in /Volumes/Install OS X Mavericks/.fseventsd
01/03/15 18:45:55,713 fseventsd[20]: log dir: /Volumes/Install OS X Mavericks/.fseventsd getting new uuid: 47C8BC98-5D0A-4148-B216-53020776D476
01/03/15 18:46:26,272 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Active'
01/03/15 18:46:29,027 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[973]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
01/03/15 18:46:30,782 locationd[54]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
01/03/15 18:46:30,913 Console[975]: Failed to connect (_consoleX) outlet from (NSApplication) to (ConsoleX): missing setter or instance variable
01/03/15 18:46:40,324 Spotlight[319]: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
```

Comment: nothing to worry about, it is the stupid Calendar Agent doing it :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 what should I do? I am really desperate , how to solve it ? it is keep randomly restarting , freezing etc

Comment: Open the Console in your Utility folder and copy some 30-50 lines here so we can have a look. It wont hurt I promise (said the Dentist to me)

Comment: Your AppleHardwareTest shows 2002D, which indicates you had a USB device connected. Disconnect all external and re-run the AHT test.

Comment: @Buscar웃  I pasted the console info above. Not unfortunately, I did not have any USB or any external stuff , I checked it 10 times :-(

Comment: Ok got it, are you trying to install Mavericks ? Also I would recommend to use disk Utility to repair the permissions and to cehck the disk.

Comment: @Buscar웃 since you said it is the problem of Calendar agent, I disable it permenetly by http://superuser.com/questions/490056/how-can-i-disable-the-calendar-agent-from-running-on-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: @Buscar웃 actually I just wanted to downgrade to Mavericks because I don't know why it keeps restarting or freezing  , I have done the disk utility , repair but it did not help at all

Comment: OK, that would explain the Mavericks stuff in the log, and you can not do that. What is interesting is the Disk Utility logs, so I need to look up. Meanwhile does it stay solid (without restarts) if you run in Safe mode. It looks like it is to messed up now, so using the cmd+r to restore the Yosemite installation, then we will see further.

Comment: Buscar웃 OK, I will restart and keep the cmd+r , then I will come back here

Answer (score 2):

If the hardware test reports an error, you may have to take it to Apple, however, the memory can be changed on your model, and that may be the source of your problem. If you replaced memory to maximize, try installing the original Apple memory according to the instructions available at:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1270

If you haven't replaced any memory, you may still be able to solve the problem yourself by using the instructions available at the location above to try your existing memory modules one at a time. If the problem goes away when either of the modules is in use by itself, you can probably assume the other one is bad, and you can then shop for a replacement or upgrade.

Comment: thanks, I cleaned installed Mavericks! now I will see whether it keeps restarting or not, If yes, I'll take it to apple shop! THNAKS

Comment: I think Trellis is likely right, you have some bad RAM. Hopefully it's not the system board and just the RAM. Note that some OS versions are pickier about hardware, so what works with Mavericks, might not with yosemite. Strange but true...

Comment: Those hardware test errors are fairly cryptic, and the RAM is generally the only thing you can test readily because duplication is commonly built in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a shutdown code which caused the crash which can be found in the log files.

This can be found either by opening *Console* app and searching for the "shutdown" word, or run the following command:

```
grep shutdown /var/log/system.log
```

This line should looks like:

> kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: X

where X is your code (either positive or negative number).

Once found, please refer to that unofficial [Shutdown Causes list](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/).

Related: [Where to find shutdown causes errors list?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/214916/22781)

This can help to identify the problem and find a more specific solution based on the findings.