# Where to find shutdown causes errors list?

Tags: macos, error, shutdown

Are there any longer shutdown causes error codes lists than this?

https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/

Answer (score 3):

I've updated that page with more shutdown causes.

[**OS X Shutdown Causes**](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/)

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an 'official' list.

Comment: Your linked page has a comment on it, "_Nobody seems to know what these codes mean but you. Where did you get this list?_", which you've not addressed.